# Come out of frame after validation of form inputs html

Tags: html

i am using frame inside a html page, there is a form in the frame. My problem is that I want to get out of the frame. When the input of form is validated I want to open the next page in full page without frame.

Comment: whats validating it ? JS, PHP ? js try at end of validation `window.location.href="WhereEver.html";` or php `header('location:whereever.html');exit;`

Comment: validating through php, its login form. I have tried header('Location:home.php') but it is opening inside the same frame.

Comment: put `<script>if (top.location != location) {
     top.location.href = document.location.href ;
   }</script>` at the top of the page you want to go to.

Comment: added as an answer, If you would accept it then the question will be closed, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put if (top.location != location) { top.location.href = document.location.href ; } at the top of the page you want to go to

Comment: Worked for me like rocket